# SQL. Вопросы оптимизации

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Доброго времени суток.

Вопросов несколько:

1. Влияет ли размер базы данных на скорость работы с ней (операции типа select, insert и т.д.), допустим в бд есть две таблицы, одна постоянно пополняется и увеличивается в размерах, другая таблица весит не очень много и к ней совершается запрос select, будет ли разница в скорости работы когда первая таблица весит 1 Мб и когда она будет весить 25 МБ?
2. Что лучше, один большой запрос к бд или несколько маленьких, и как это работает?

P.S.

Использую сервер MySql для бд, работаю с ней с помощью php

Comment: 1. С увеличением размера таблицы скорость всех операций с ней будет замедляться, не обязательно линейно. 2. Зависит от конкретного запроса и конкретной задачи. На этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа

Comment: 1. Другие таблицы как-то влияют на скорость работы с определенной таблицей? 2. Например, в интернет-магазине на конкретной странице 10 товаров, для каждого из них нужна картинка, для этого необходимо выполнить 10 запросов к бд, при этом получить эти картинки сразу вместе с товарами нельзя. Есть какой-то массив с id товаров, в foreach выполняется 10 запросов в бд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Не влияет. Пока Вы работаете с одной таблицей Вас не должно интересовать что происходит с другими таблицами или другими базами на сервер
2. Как работают выборки

   1. Отправить запрос на сервер
   2. Распарсить запрос на сервере
   3. Найти нужные записи
   4. Сложить записи в буфер
   5. Отправить буфер клиенту

Таким образом при куче мелких запросов пункты 1-3 выполняются для каждого запроса. Особенно тяжелый 3 пункт. Возможен вариант, когда серверу придется на каждый запрос сканировать всю таблицу, чтобы найти нужные записи. Пункты 4-5, просто сложатся вместе и никакого отличия между мелкими запросами и одним большим не будет.

Таким образом, один запрос почти всегда предпочтительнее. Чем куча мелких. Кроме двух исключений:

1. Объем выбранных записей больше чем памяти на клиенте или сервере
2. Не факт, что все выбранные записи понадобятся. Например, клиенту совсем не нужно показывать 1000 записей. Достаточно показать 100, а следующие 100 подгрузить уже при необходимости

К слову, даже размер записи не будет влиять на скорость обработки. Т.е. у Вас могут лежать в этой же таблице многомегабайтные БЛОБы, но пока Вы не обращаетесь к ним, у Вас производительность не меняется

Comment: 1) Если со второй таблицей идет работа, то это нагрузка на СУБД и на файловую систему. И тогда от размера этой таблицы будет зависеть скорость работы с первой

Comment: 2) Говоря о скорости работы запросов, все зависит от планов их выполнения. И точка. Указанные вами факторы могут влиять на построение плана, но не стоит на них опираться при выборе того, как запрос писать

Comment: @Viktorov 1) Говорить, что СУБД тормозит из-за работы соседнего запроса, все равно, что говорить, что СУБД медленная, т.к. не позволяет утащить мегабайт данных по GPRS подключению. 2) Наличие данных в соседней таблице никак не повлияют на построения плана. Если бомбардировать сервер одинаковыми запросами с разными параметрами - это приведет только к построению кучи одинаковых планов